# Functional equation for $\theta$ function using functional equation of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: functional-equations, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, theta-functions

Let $$\theta(t) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}e^{-n^2 \pi t}.$$ We can derive a functional equation for $\theta$ using Poisson summation formula: $$\theta(1/t) = \sqrt t \theta(t). $$

Riemann uses the above functional equation for $\theta$ to write $$\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{\frac {s}{2}-1} \frac{\theta(x)-1}{2}dx $$ and then proceeds to establish the functional equation: $$\xi(s) = \xi(1-s) $$ where $\xi(s) = s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s).$

Now, my question is just out of curiosity: Can we deduce functional equation of $\theta$ from the functional equation of $\zeta?$ My approach would be to use inverse Mellin's transform. Are there other approaches?

Comment: The inverse Mellin transform gives this directly. After that, it might depend on how exotic you want to go. Something not really in the spirit would be to pass through Eisenstein series, which have functional equations that can be proved using the functional equations for $\zeta(s)$ and appropriate Dirichlet $L$-functions. The weight $1$, real-analytic, Selberg-type Eisenstein series $E(s, z)$ has a pole at $s = \frac{3}{4}$, and the residue is precisely $\theta(z)$ (actually times $y^{3/4}$). Then the functional equation of the Eisenstein series descends to $\theta(z)$.

Comment: This is surely possible, and the idea is generalized to [converse theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_theorem) for L functions